# Ejabberd catch client disconnect

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, exmpp

I run ejabberd and bot written in erlang/exmpp. I connect to this bot some jabber clients. How can i catch client disconnect?

Answer (score 2):

What you mean by catch?
For debugging add ?DEBUG in ejabberd_sm:close_session.
For tracing dbg over ejabberd_c2s:terminate and the same ejabberd_sm:close_session.
For application call subscribe to sm_remove_connection_hook.
Maybe implement your own hook and use custom one?

Comment: Client send message to bot and bot send message to client, then client go to offline, how can i catch this moment and know client JID which go to offline?

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know If I understood you right, but if you have the power to make the clients send a directed presence to the bot, when users go off-line then the server will send notification of the disconnect to the bot.

You can find some documentation in [RFC 3921](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html)
here's a litle extract.

> 5.1.4.  Directed Presence
>
> A user MAY send directed presence to another entity (i.e., a
>   presence stanza with a 'to' attribute whose value is the JID of the
>   other entity and with either no 'type' attribute or a 'type' attribute
>   whose value is "unavailable"). There are three possible cases:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. If the user sends directed presence to an entity that is not in
>      the user's roster with a subscription type of "from" or "both" after
>      having sent initial presence and before sending unavailable presence
>      broadcast, the user's server MUST route or deliver the full XML of
>      that presence stanza to the entityv(...); however, if the available
>      resource from which the user sent the directed presence become
>      unavailable, the user's server MUST broadcast that unavailable
>      presence to the entity (if the user has not yet sent directed
>      unavailable presence to that entity).
> 3. ...

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to check when user closes c2s connection rather than checking when user sends offline stanza, you can edit and customize ejabberd_c2s.erl for this purpose. Inside ejabber_c2s the function which deals with disconnect is terminate/3 (line # 1425) and you can find the jabber id of client quite easily.